# Vue.js + get selected li item of ul

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a list displayed like a dropdown -

Each of the items except 'Create New Filter' is bound to a key so i can uniquely identify the li items.

I want to know how can i get the selected li item on save and do operations accordingly

What would be the good approach for this so i can understand when 'Create new filter' is clicked or when other li items are selected

[image]

Below is the code -

```
 <ul>
     <li v-on:click="create">Create New</li>
     <li v-for="item in list" :key="item.id" v-on:click="Change(item.id,item.text)">{{ item.text }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good approach to me.  Your dropdown does two different things; it shouldn't.  Provide another UI element, like a button, for kicking off the "add" function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding this approach is not good, I am not sure why you are building dropdown by using `<ul>` and `<li>` instead of `select` element as it is a form element and provide a better way to get the selected option value by the help of `v-model` directive.

Anyhow I worked as per your requirement and came up with the solution.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '.dropdown',
  data: {
    list: [{
      id: 1,
      text: 'First Filter'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      text: 'First Filter 2021'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      text: 'Full Filter'
    }],
    selectedListItem: null
  },
  methods: {
    create() {
      console.log('New filter Create Called');
    },
    getSelected (item) {
      this.selectedListItem = item;
    },
    save() {
      if (this.selectedListItem) {
        console.log(this.selectedListItem);
      } else {
        console.log('No list option selected');
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Select Filter" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"/>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li v-on:click="create">Create New</li>
    <li v-for="item in list" :key="item.id" v-on:click="getSelected(item)">{{ item.text }}</li>
  </ul>
  <button @click="save">SAVE</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it works. Requirement was to create an editable dropdown which can allow to enter and a dropdown to select values. Hence i have created it using li and ul